# C# Interface Different Variable Types in Repository Methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, interface, repository

I would like to implement a interface and repository pattern. My different repositories can have type data types,

First one is (String-int, char-long)

Second one is (Char-double, double-string).
Pattern keeps going, we have around 50 different methods.We are changing our interface/repositories to another database system, etc.

How would I edit the edit the interface below, to allow different data types? Thanks,

```
public interface ITransactionRepository
{
    void SearchTransactionbyCategoryCustomerId(Category, CustomerId ); // what should I write here?
    void SearchTransactionbyProductDepartment(Product, Department); 
    ......
}


public class TransactionRepository1: IRepository
{
    void SearchTransactionbyCategoryCustomerId(string Category, int CustomerId);
    void SearchTransactionbyProductDepartment(char Product, long Department); 
    ......
}

public class TransactionRepository2: IRepository
{
    void SearchTransactionbyCategoryCustomerId(char Category, double CustomerId);
    void SearchTransactionbyProductDepartment(double Product, string Department); 
    ......
}
```

Comment: Think about it for a moment. Let's imagine you could do `where T: string, char` (which you cannot), how would those methods look like? `if T is string...`?

Comment: Surely this isn't a representation of your actual system though...? Can you post something that more closely resembles what you're working with?

Comment: Should `IRepository` really be `ITransactionRepository` or is something missing?

Comment: I'm curious why you would represent the same thing (`Product`) with `Product`s, `char`s, and `double`s. Couldn't you standardize that rather than worry about all the combinations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your interface as generic and specify the actual types in the implementation,

```
public interface ITransactionRepository<TCategory, TCustomerId, TProduct, TDepartment>
{
    void SearchTransactionbyCategoryCustomerId(TCategory Category, TCustomerId CustomerId );
    void SearchTransactionbyProductDepartment(TProduct Product, TDepartment Department); 
    ......
}


public class TransactionRepository1: ITransactionRepository<string, int, char, long>
{
    void SearchTransactionbyCategoryCustomerId(string Category, int CustomerId);
    void SearchTransactionbyProductDepartment(char Product, long Department); 
    ......
}

public class TransactionRepository2: ITransactionRepository<char, double, double, string>
{
    void SearchTransactionbyCategoryCustomerId(char Category, double CustomerId);
    void SearchTransactionbyProductDepartment(double Product, string Department); 
    ......
}
```

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils My  bad, copy paste error. Code adjusted.